# Office Word Library - the result of searching by wildcards

Tags: c#, regex, com, ms-word, ms-office

I have a MS Word 2003 documents that contains placeholders such as `/FirstName/, /LastName/`, etc... I used Microsoft Office 12 Library to read the file and search by wildcards with `Find.Text = "/[A-Z]*/"`. It works fine, and `Find.Execute` does find the placeholder exactly. But because it returns only the boolean value, I don't know how to get the placeholder itself.

Can you please show me how to get the text that is searched by a wildcard option

Comment: Please provide information on the methods in question.  Please also provide the code you are using.

Comment: showing your code will help out Hoang

Comment: Thank u, I posted the code below

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using word bookmarks instead of placeholders, because the text isn't shown to the user and you could use something la this to automatically insert text wherever you want because you can get the range of a specific bookmark:

```
protected void insertTextAt(string bookmarkName, string text,
            bool useDefaults = true, string fontName = "Arial", 
            int fontSize = 11, int bold = 0,bool newLine = true)
        {
            try
            {
                Object oBookMarkName = bookmarkName;
                WordInterop.Range wRng =
                    this.wDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMarkName).Range;
                wRng.Text = text;
                if (!useDefaults)
                {
                    wRng.Font.Bold = bold;
                    wRng.Font.Name = fontName;
                    wRng.Font.Size = fontSize;
                }
                if (newLine)
                {
                    wRng.Text += "\r\n";
                }
                wRng.Font.Bold = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                String exceptionString = String.Format("Bookmark {0} could not"
                +" be found in template {1}",bookmarkName,this.template);
                throw new Exception(exceptionString,e);
            }

        }
```

Comment: I share the documents with an existing program. If I changed placeholder to bookmark, it may cause the old program to function incorrectly. Btw thank you

Comment: You don't have to change the placeholder to o bookmark you just have to mark the entire placeholder as a bookmark and the text will automatically be overridden, this way you've got backwards compatibility. And if you insist on using just placeholder try this `Application.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = "Found";` and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f65x8z3d(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, for your interest.
Firstly, this is the `letter.doc` files

> Dear /FirstName/ /MiddleName/ /LastName/:
>
> Welcome to our program. We are committed to giving you the highest
>   quality of customer service....

I also have a `Dictionary<string, string> Data` that store the key/value for each placeholder

```
    ...
    "/FirstName/" : "read from database"
    "/MiddleName/" : "read from database"
    "/LastName/" : "read from database"
    ...
```

And I have a method that reads the .doc file and replaces the placeholders :

```
    oWordApp = new MSWord.ApplicationClass();
    doc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
                                                    ref missing, ref readOnly,
                                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible,
                                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    doc.Activate();
    doc.Select();

    oWordApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
    oWordApp.Selection.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
    oWordApp.Selection.Find.Wrap = MSWord.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
    oWordApp.Selection.Find.Text = "/[A-Z]*/";

    bool isFound = true;
    while(isFound == true) {
        isFound = oWordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        if( isFound == true ) {
            //use the database to do the replacing
            //how to get the placeholder itself, such as "/FirstName/", "/LastName/",...
        }
    }
```